# copy+paste displayed values Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a column with formatted ids (Brazilian CPF).

The user input is 12345678900 and the displayed value is 123.456.789-00.

If I copy and paste this column to another column, the values pasted are in 12345678900 format.

I want to copy the "displayed values" of a column to another column using google script what's the simple code for that?

I am trying using a loop, but my sheet is too big and it is very slow!

Updating cell with the displayed value format is not working.

```
while (primeira_linha <= ultima_linha){
          var cpf_formatado = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("2020").getRange(primeira_linha,10).getDisplayValue();
          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("2020").getRange(primeira_linha,10).setValue(cpf_formatado);
          primeira_linha++;
```

Comment: Test to use cell.text not Cell.value

Answer (score 3):

- You want to get values from the column "J" on the sheet of `2020` in the active Spreadsheet using `getDisplayValue`.
- You want to put the retrieved values to the other column as the text.
- You want to reduce the process cost of your current script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Modification point:

- In your script, `getDisplayValue` and `setValue` are used in the loop. By this, the process cost becomes high.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, in order to reduce the process cost, `getDisplayValues` and `setValues` are used without using the loop. So the values are retrieved as the text values, and put them as the text values.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows. Before you run the script, please set the variables.

```
var primeira_linha = ##;  // Please set the start row.
var ultima_linha = ##;  // Please set the end row.
var sourceColumn = 10;  // Source column. In this case, it's the column "J".
var destinationColumn = 10;  // Please set the column you want to put the values. In this case, it's the column "J".

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("2020");
var values = sheet.getRange(primeira_linha, sourceColumn, ultima_linha - primeira_linha + 1).getDisplayValues();
sheet.getRange(primeira_linha, destinationColumn, values.length, 1).setNumberFormat("@").setValues(values);
```

- From your script, it seems that the values retrieved with `getDisplayValues` from the column "J" are put to the same column. So the above modified script is the same process.
- And in this case, in order to modify the cell format, I used `setNumberFormat("@")`. In this case, the values are put as the text. If you don't want to modify the cell format. Please remove `.setNumberFormat("@")`.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, `copyTo` is used. In this case, the values are copied with the cell format.

#### Modified script:

```
var primeira_linha = ##;  // Please set the start row.
var ultima_linha = ##;  // Please set the end row.
var sourceColumn = 10;  // Source column. In this case, it's the column "J".
var destinationColumn = 10;  // Please set the column you want to put the values. In this case, it's the column "J".

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("2020");
var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(primeira_linha, sourceColumn, ultima_linha - primeira_linha + 1);
var destinationRange = sheet.getRange(primeira_linha, destinationColumn);
sourceRange.copyTo(destinationRange);
```

### References:

- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [setNumberFormat()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormat(String))
- [copyTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Pattern 1: You are the best! Great! Thanks

Comment: @RobertoJunior If this answer is acceptable, perhaps you would be willing to accept this answer by checking off the icon just to the left of the answer.

Comment: @Roberto Junior Is there anything that I can do for your question? If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I would like to think of about the solution.